# Minimum of $|x−t_1|+|x−t_2|+…+|x−t_{99}|$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

Let $t_1<t_2<t_3<⋯<t_{99}$ be real numbers. Consider the  function 
$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=|x−t_1|+|x−t_2|+…+|x−t_{99}|$$

Show that $f(x)$ will attain a minimum value at $x=t_{50}$.

Comment: Show us your efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the graph of $y=f(x)$ is continuous.

For $x\in(-\infty,t_1]$, the graph is a half-line with slope $-99$.

For $x\in[t_{99},\infty)$, the graph is a half-line with slope $99$.

For $x\in [t_k,t_{k+1}]$, the graph is a line segment joining $(t_k,f(t_k))$ and $(t_{k+1},f(t_{k+1}))$, with slope $(99-k)-k=99-2k$.

$f$ is decreasing for $x\in(-\infty,x_{50}]$ and is increasing for $x\in[x_{50},\infty)$.

$f$ attains its minimum at $x=t_{50}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just one line :

> The value of the mean deviation is minimum if the deviations are taken from the median

Comment: +1 but this one line needs to be proved also. At least introductory statistics books almost always by rule don't prove it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Actually, I know it's [geometric proof](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00220973.1957.11010587) only. Therefore it's the same as proof as in the answer provided by CY Kwong. But if OP is interested in it's proof, shouldn't (s)he Google it? I have provided a path to proceed.